# Adding arrays to a list object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have the following code and an array is added within the initiators:

```
  var GraphList = new List<object>{
  new []{ "Year", "Sales", "Expenses"},
  new []{ "2010", "2012", "2001" },
  new []{ "80", "100", "200"}
```

How can I add a new array not using the constructor i.e.

```
GraphList.Add.new []{ "80", "100", "200"};
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work (I assume that `GraphList` is in scope):

```
GraphList.Add(new []{ "80", "100", "200"});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
GraphList.Add(new[] { "80", "100", "200" });
```